# Simple 'database' in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, sizeof

My task was to create pseudodatabase in c++. There are 3 tables given, that store name(char*), age(int), and sex (bool). Write a program allowing to :
- add new data to the tables
- show all records
- sort tables with criteria :
      - name increasing/decreasing
      - age increasing/decreasing
      - sex

Using function templates is a must. Also size of arrays must be variable, depending on the amount of records.

I have some code but there are still problems there.
Here's what I have:
Function tabSize() for returning size of array. But currently it returns size of pointer I guess :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename TYPE> int tabSize(TYPE *T)
{
   int size = 0;  
   size = sizeof(T) / sizeof(T[0]);
   return size;
}
```

How to make it return size of array, not its pointer ?

Next the most important : add() for adding new elements. Inside first I get the size of array (but hence it returns value of pointer, and not size it's of no use now :/). Then I think I must check if TYPE of data is char. Or am I wrong ?

```
// add(newElement, table)
template<typename TYPE> TYPE add(TYPE L, TYPE *T)
{   
   int s = tabSize(T);
//here check if TYPE = char. If yes, get the length of the new name
       int len = 0;
       while (L[len] != '\0') {
           len++;
       }
//current length of table   
   int tabLen = 0; 
   while (T[tabLen] != '\0') {
       tabLen++;
   }    
//if TYPE is char   
//if current length of table + length of new element exceeds table size create new table      
   if(len + tabLen > s)
   {
        int newLen = len + tabLen;
        TYPE newTab = new [newLen];
        for(int j=0; j < newLen; j++ ){
            if(j == tabLen -1){
                for(int k = 0; k < len; k++){
                    newTab[k] = 
                }
            }
            else {
                newTab[j] = T[j];
            }
        }
   }
//else check if tabLen + 1 is greater than s. If yes enlarge table by 1.               
}
```

Am I thinking correct here ?

Last functions show() is correct I guess :

```
template<typename TYPE> TYPE show(TYPE *L)
{
   int len = 0;
   while (L[len] == '\0') {
       len++;
   }

   for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
   {
      cout << L[i] << endl;
   }    
}
```

and problem with sort() is as follows : Ho can I influence if sorting is decreasing or increasing ? I'm using bubble sort here.

```
template<typename TYPE> TYPE sort(TYPE *L, int sort)
{
   int s = tabSize(L);               

   int len = 0; 
   while (L[len] == '\0') {
       len++;
   }
//add control increasing/decreasing sort
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            if(L[i]>L[j])
            {
                int temp=L[i];
                L[i]=L[j];
                L[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

And main function to run it :

```
int main()
{
    int sort=0;
    //0 increasing, 1 decreasing
    char * name[100];
    int age[10];
    bool sex[10];

    char c[] = "Tom";  
    name[0] = "John";
    name[1] = "Mike";

    cout << add(c, name) << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your design, you must have a variable that maintains the size of the array.  This value will be adjusted as items are added or removed.  The C++ language has no facilities for obtaining the size of an array variable.

Also, prefer to use `std::string` instead of `char *`.  If your instructor says to use `char *`, then provide it as a parameter to your functions, but convert to `std::string` inside functions and classes.  This will make your life a lot easier.

Don't implement your own sort algorithms.  Prefer to use `std::sort` and different compare **functions**.  The `std::sort` algorithm has been tested and will save you time and effort.

Implement the `Visitor` design pattern.  This will allow you to access your tables in different ways without writing new methods in the table class.  For example, with a `Visitor` base class, you can derive classes for reading from files, writing to files and displaying content without changing the table class.

Lastly, don't use `system("pause")` which may not be portable.  Instead, prefer `cin.ignore` which can be found in `std::istream::ignore`.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest storing as `std::string` internally if the assignment says to use `char*` unless you ask your instructor (or TA) first. While in any real-world scenario, you would want to use `std::string`, part of the point of the assignment might be to learn manual memory management, and if they read your code and find `std::string`, you might lose credit for it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some sort of terminator to the array, there is no easy way to get the size of an array pointed to by `T`.

You would have to do a loop through the array pointed to by `T` and count up elements until you find a terminator. (E.G. `'\0'` for `char *`)