# How do I implement a simple relational database?

Tags: c++

Note that this question is about C++ *only*, I am not interested in using existing database libraries, nor am I seeking a generic solution to "databases in c++". I have a specific question and am after the most efficient (in terms time, space and best practice) solution to the problem below.

Suppose I have a series of books, described by `Id`, `ISBN`, `Author`, and `Name`. The `Name` column will be an ID which relates to a separate table of authors, containing the columns `Id`, `Surname`, `First Name`. I want to be able to *efficiently* search by Name as well as by Author. How would I go about structuring this, and what containers would I use?

This topic has been broached several times on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760840/simple-database-in-c) and [elsewhere](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/811006-implementing-database-concepts-using-c), but never with an answer relating specifically to C++ or to an implementation not using existing libraries.

The naive solution would be simply to create 2 separate classes: `Author` and `Book`:

```
class Book
{
public:
  int id;
  std::string isbn;
  Author* author;
  std::string name;
};

class Author
{
public:
  int id;
  std::string surname;
  std::string givenName;
};
```

I could then create vectors of Book and Author (pointers). But how would I efficiently index these? Suppose I want to find a book by its ISBN; how can I do that in constant or at least logarithmic time? Is this possible? Is there standard practice for this kind of problem?

Comment: This one where I wish there were a pre-emptive "vote against closing" capability. This is a perfectly reasonable question, that's entirely answerable. While there isn't one absolute answer, there's reasonable factual support for choosing between the possibilities, not just opinion.

Comment: This is a very general question, and any good answer would be fairly generic -- not specific to C++.  This is assuming you want a real, reasonably large and robust DB, vs simply a set of hash maps.

Comment: @HotLicks I want a solution that efficiently allows me to sort or index by any member of `Book` or `Author` using c++ for a potentially large number of those items.

Comment: How large?  How persistent?  It's fairly easy to cobble something together with hash maps, as I said, but that won't handle 10s of thousands of entries, nor will it permit a persistent DB.  (Take a look at open source SQLite.)

Comment: @HotLicks Large as in *large but in memory*, I am not interested in persistence or existing database implementations. The purpose of the question is to identify how I can index these relational tables in constant or logarithmic time.

Comment: @ausairman: If you don't care about persistence, then SQLite and MySQL does support in-memory database. Also, you might want to check out in-memory key-value database like Redis or memcached.

Comment: @LieRyan, I am more interested in how this would be done in native c++

Comment: @ausairman: Why must it be native C++? Is it for learning purpose or is there a reason for avoiding external dependency?

Comment: So, just build hash tables over the data you want to search on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the standard containers don't support indexing by multiple keys -- each container supports only a single key. That can be a composite key, so if you have three books with the same title by different authors, you can specify both the title and author to find only one of those. None of the standard containers, however, supports searching separately by title or author.

The [Boost Multi-Index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) library supports multiple keys per item fairly directly. The Multi-Index tutorial has [example of creating foreign keys](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_index/doc/examples.html#example6) much like you're interested in using.

Multi-Index supports both (red-black) tree-based and hash-based indices. As usual, you get a trade-off between the two -- hashed indices usually give faster lookup of a single item, but tree-based indices support inequalities, so they're generally better if you want things like searching for ranges (e.g., "books by authors with surnames from 'C' to 'L'").

Answer (score 3):

The standard data structure for an index are hash map if you only need reverse mapping or a binary search tree if you also need sorting. In C++, these are [unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) and [map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) respectively.

> Suppose I want to find a book by its ISBN;

Create `unordered_map<std::string,Book*>` and searching will be constant time.

Comment: Ok, so I would create an unordered_map for member of `Book` that I want to be able to search for? If I then choose to delete an instance of `Book`, I would call `unordered_map::find` for each of these maps?

Comment: I'd suggest using `std::shared_ptr<Book>` as the mapped type, that way you can keep the single book in several lookup tables and not have to worry about manual memory management.  If you want to delete a book, you have to delete it from all of the reference tables.